# Does creating more SQL AGENT steps for deleting records will be a performance gain or loss

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

I got a task to delete 9 million record from a table

so iam planning to do via SQL Agent job, i have prepared script to delete as like 50000 records from one delete statement

So now do i need to create single jobs with many steps or i can create various jobs new jobs without schedules?

Which will be more resource efficient?

Note:Log backup is configured for every 20 mins

Thanks,
Vishvas.K

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting 1 millions rows in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785439/deleting-1-millions-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: There are plenty of answers on deleting large volumes.  Any statements that hit > 5K rows will cause a table lock, so if you schedule multiple jobs to purge 50K each, you'll just wind up locking up your table.  Batched deletion is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about below quick and easy solution -

```
  WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
     DELETE TOP(5000)
     FROM Table_Name
     WHERE <condition_here>
     IF @@ROWCOUNT < 5000 BREAK;
  END
```